# How to get Pimcore Admin email address to send him some notice?

Tags: pimcore

How to get email address configured in
Settings -> System Settings -> Debug
to be able to send some notification to it from my application?

Where is it stored?

Answer (score 0):

### Where is is stored?

After clicking 'Save' in your settings you can see this value stored in /config/parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    email.debug.email_addresses: 'some@email.com'
```

### How to inject the .yml param to class variable

In you services.yml add your service, e.g.:

```
SomeBundle\Service\SomeSender:
    arguments:
        $emails: '%email.debug.email_addresses%'
```

Then in your class you can access this param in **2 approaches**:

```
public function __construct(string $emails, private ParameterBagInterface $params)
{
    $emailsArray =  $this->params->get('email.debug.email_addresses');
    var_dump($emails, $emailsArray);
}
```

Both types of injections are good but %param% injection allows you easily change email used in this Class with no code change, in yml file.

You can use injected value to send email to Pimcore Admin:

```
    $email = reset($emails);
    $mail = new \Pimcore\Mail();
    $mail->to($email);
    $mail->html("<b>some</b> rich text");
    $mail->send();
```